# Can I place an element at specific pixel?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm coming from a flash/flex background, so forgive me if this is an off question, but I'm wondering if I can place an element at exactly some pixel position on the screen. Pixel can be substituted for any measurement of position.

Is this even possible in javascript? How do you control where elements are drawn in javascript/html?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
myEl.style.position = 'absolute';
myEl.style.left     = x+'px';
myEl.style.top      = y+'px';
```

Note that this will position the element absolutely with respect to its positioned parent; you may need to account for the position(s) of the positioned parent(s) to get it absolute to the screen.

Comment: Can I use it some relative measure, like percent?

Comment: @Alex Yes, you can set the `top`, `left`, `width`, `height`, `right`, or `bottom` all in a [CSS length unit](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#values) or [percentage](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#percentage-units). See the [`top`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-top) documentation, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Using CSS, you can set the position of any element to an absolute value, like so:

```
#myelement {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
}
```

One caveat to that is the position can be set to relative to any *other* element in your HTML. By default, it's relative to the window. You can make the position relative to any other element like so:

```
#mycontaining-element {
    position: relative;
}
```

The HTML might look like this:

```
<div id="mycontaining-element">
    <h1 id="myelement">Headline</h1>
</div>
```

More info here: http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is called [absolute positioning](http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Absolute_Layouts).